# How to find the two power of the number

Tags: c

I have a number, which power of two, example 128== which is 2 power 7.

how to find what is the two power of the number.

with very minimum code.

Answer (score 6):

Try this,

```
int a = 128, ret = 0;
while (a) { ret++; a >>= 1; }
```

Or,

```
int a = 128, ret = 0;
#define check(i) if ((-1 << i) & a) { ret += i; a >>= i; }
check (16)
check (8)
check (4)
check (2)
check (1)
```

This works because `-1 == 0xffffffffff...` a.k.a. an endless string of 1's.  So I basically perform binary search to locate the index of the highest set bit.

Comment: @MadHatter, question is not about checking if the number is power of two or not. it is: i know it is a power of two and i want to find power. example 128== 2 power 7. how to find 7 with minimum operation.

Comment: any other simple method other than using loop??

Comment: @suhel You could use a lot of `if` statements... I'll edit it and show you.

Comment: sorry, i did not understand your solution, also one doubt here: ((-1 << i) & a), you are using bitwise & on signed operands? is it fine ?

Comment: @VishalSantharam READ the question, the OP is asking for binary logarithm of a power of 2 not if it's a power of two.

Comment: for check(16), in above code what would be ret ?.. if i understood this ret will be 0, as if statement fails... correct?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the other answers, I believe the number needs to be decremented before going into the while loop to get the correct answer:

```
  public static int getPowersOfTwo(int number) {
    int powersOfTwo = 0;
    number--;  // has the effect of zeroing out the most significant non-zero bit
    while (number > 0) {
      powersOfTwo++;
      number >>= 1;
    }

    return powersOfTwo;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do it:

```
int num=64,pow=0;
while(num){++pow;num>>=1;}
```

It is very simple and since it uses byte operations, it is quite fast too